# How to implement Axios.delete in react and delete from Mongodb by id

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, mern

I am new to MERN (programming itself) , I am trying to make a delete from database by ID from front-end. I would like to be able to click a button on an item and have it deleted from database.

```
useEffect(() =>{
  Axios.post('api/product/editProducts')
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.success){
        setProperty(response.data.products)
      }else {
        alert('Failed to get product information')
      }
    })
})

return (
  <div>
    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '5rem '}}>
      <h1>Edit Properties</h1>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Title</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Rent/Sale</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
          <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {Property.map(property => (
          <tr key={property.id}>
            <td>{property.title}</td>
            <td>{property.description}</td>
            <td>{property.price}</td>
            <td>{property.properties}</td>                            
            <td>{property.rentorbuy}</td>
            <td>{EditBtn }</td>
            <td><a onClick={handleDeleteProperty}>{DeleteBtn}</a></td>
          </tr>
        ))}
```

Using the above code I am able to fetch products from database.

```
router.post("/editProducts", auth, (req,res) => {
  Product.find()
    .exec((err,products) => {
      if(err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err})
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, products })
    })
});
```

[product display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lDJm.jpg)

Can someone help me with code and routes of how to click on the delete btn as shown in the picture and have that specific item deleted from the Database?

Answer (score 0):

- You can do something like this

Frontend

```js
const handleDeleteProperty = async (id) => {
    try{
        const res = await Axios.delete('url', id);
        if(res.data.success){
            alert(res.data.msg);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

```js
<td><a onClick={e => handleDeleteProperty(property.id)}>{DeleteBtn}</a></td>
```

Backend

```js
router.delete('url', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try{
        await Product.findByIdAndDelete(req.body.id);
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: 'Product Deleted' });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

- Now that that's done, you can handle the errors more elegantly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AmanBhardwaj . I will try it on my new project